# Passenger Apache Module install - installer not finding installed libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I am trying to host a Rails app, in a VPS server. The server already, has Apache, installed, so I am trying to install passenger first, then passenger-apache-module.

I have installed RVM as the user, and ruby 1.9.3 and set it as the default ruby. Then, I installed passenger gem, version 3.0.17, as we are migrating the rails app, and the passenger version in the old server is 3.0.17. I was able to install passenger gem with the command `gem install passenger -v 3.0.17`.

After installing passenger, I went ahead and tried to install `passenger-apache-module` using the `passenger-install-apache2-module` command. I am getting this output:

```
Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... not found
 * Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
 * OpenSSL development headers... not found
 * Zlib development headers... not found
 * Ruby development headers... found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
 * RubyGems... found
 * Rake... found at /home/federaltitle/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/rake
 * rack... found
 * Apache 2... found at /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
 * Apache 2 development headers... found at /usr/bin/apxs
 * Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers... found at /usr/local/apache/bin/apr-1-config
 * Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers... found at /usr/local/apache/bin/apu-1-config

Some required software is not installed.
But don't worry, this installer will tell you how to install them.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.
```

When I hit Enter, I am getting this output:

```
Installation instructions for required software

 * To install GNU C++ compiler:
   Please run yum install gcc-c++ as root.

 * To install Curl development headers with SSL support:
   Please run yum install curl-devel as root.

 * To install OpenSSL development headers:
   Please run yum install openssl-devel as root.

 * To install Zlib development headers:
   Please run yum install zlib-devel as root.

If the aforementioned instructions didn't solve your problem, then please take
a look at the Users Guide:

  /home/federaltitle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-3.0.17/doc/Users guide Apache.html
```

But, when I try to install the libraries mentioned in the message (`yum install gcc-c++`, `yum install curl-devel`, `yum install openssl-devel`, `yum install zlib-devel`) as root user, it is saying all the libraries are already installed and up-to-date.

## Server Details

OS - CENTOS 6.4 x86_64

Comment: Passenger 3 is very old, and when something goes wrong with dependency autodetection there are few ways to figure out why. You should upgrade to the latest version of Passenger, v4.0.19, and run the installer with the environment variable VERBOSE=1. That will tell you exactly why it wasn't able to find dependencies despite them being installed.

Comment: I was able to install the rvm, ruby and passenger as root, and the issue was fixed. Something to do with permission, when done as user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the rvm, ruby and passenger as root, and the issue was fixed. Something to do with permission, when done as user. But I had to do some workarounds for the user related activities on the ruby part like `bundle install`, `rake assets:precompile` (had to do this as root, so gave sudo permission for the local user to perform these).